# How to attach a listener to sysfs files?

Tags: filesystems, linux-kernel, inotify, sysfs, async

How to watch for `sysfs` file changes (like `/sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/operstate`) and execute a command on content change?

- `inotify` does not work on `sysfs`
- I don't want to poll. I want to set a listener with a callback routine once

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have not read the source code that populates `operstate`, but generally, reading a file in sysfs executes some code on the kernel side that returns the bytes you're reading. So, without you reading `operstate`, it has no "state". The value is not stored anywhere.

> How to watch for sysfs file change

Since these are not actually files, the concept "change" doesn't exist.

There's probably a better way to achieve what you want! `netlink` was designed *specifically* for the task of monitoring networking state; it's [easy to interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261759/get-notified-about-network-interface-change-on-linux). For example, this minimally modified sample code from `man 7 netlink` might already solve your problem:

```
       struct sockaddr_nl sa;

       memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
       sa.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
       // Link state change notifications:
       sa.nl_groups = RTMGRP_LINK;

       fd = socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_ROUTE);
       bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &sa, sizeof(sa));
```

Generally, if this is not about ethernet-level connectivity but, say, connectivity to some IP network (or, the internet), systemd/NetworkManager is the route you'd go on a modern system instead.

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for a generic solution for /sys/ files (which are actually kernel calls). How can I attach a listener to these kernel calls from a bash script?

Comment: you can't. That's what I said in my first sentence. Again, they are **not** files. You can't "listen" to something you have to *initiate*.

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator You've recognized that they're kernel calls. You can't generally know if what a call returns has changed unless you run it and compare. That's effectively polling. No way around it if you want a generic solution.

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator there's no "generic solution" for all `/sys` files. You can watch for *some* events with netlink sockets: `NETLINK_ROUTE` for stuff related to interfaces, network links and such, and `NETLINK_KOBJECT_UEVENT` for plug-n-play devices and related stuff. Not all netlink interfaces are *watchable*; in particular `NETLINK_INET_DIAG` and `NETLINK_SOCK_DIAG` are not -- you can get info about existing sockets, but you cannot be notified when a new one is created, connected, etc.

Comment: @MarcusMüller the last paragraph is pretty dumb: systemd and NetworkManager are **not** present in ~99.99% of "modern" Linux devices, and if they're present, they're using the very same rtnetlink(7) interfaces to get info about ethernet links, ip addresses, routes, etc.

Comment: @UncleBilly "99.99%": `[[citation needed]]`; I'll argue that systems where you execute bash scripts are not android devices nor busybox embedded systems, so that leaves us with servers and desktop distros, and correct my "dumbness"; for containers with externally controlled networking, the question makes little sense. So we remain at systems that actually have a full userland init system. And now I'm looking for the Linux distro that has a significant market share AND doesn't ship with systemd/NetworkManager.

Comment: There's isn't anything in this Q&A about either bash or init systems. And yes, you could use rtnetlink(7) directly or via ip-* tools (which **are**  present on busybox systems, too) to monitor not just "ethernet-level" connectivity, but also ip addresses, routes, and other such stuff without bothering with limitations of NetworkManager or systemd.

Answer (score 4):

As the good Müller already has explained you can not *monitor* `sysfs` files as they are part of virtual file system and does not act like *normal files*.

I ended up downing myself into some C, and whilst rather untested and not very good looking, a botched [fragment of this](http://www.mail-archive.com/davinci-linux-open-source@linux.davincidsp.com/msg05405/netlink_test.c), as a broader example from `netlink` and [`rnetlink`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html):

```
./realtimnetlink
Monitoring
RTM NEWLINK enp12s0 DOWN
RTM NEWLINK enp12s0 UP
RTM NEWLINK eth10 DOWN
RTM NEWADDR eth10
RTM NEWLINK eth10 UP
```

Compile by `gcc -o foo foo.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/rtnetlink.h>
#include <net/if.h>

#define E_PRINT(f_, ...) fprintf(stderr, ("ERROR NetLink: %s" f_ "\n"), ##__VA_ARGS__)

int open_netlink()
{
    int soc; // fd
    struct sockaddr_nl sa;

    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
    sa.nl_groups = RTMGRP_LINK | RTMGRP_IPV4_IFADDR | RTMGRP_IPV6_IFADDR;
    soc = socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_ROUTE);
    if (soc < 0) {
        perror("INIT socket: ");
        return -1;
    }
    if (bind(soc, (struct sockaddr *) &sa, sizeof(sa)) == -1) {
        perror("INIT bind_socket:");
        return -1;
    }
    return soc;
}
int event_read(
    int sockint,
    int (*msg_handler)(struct nlmsghdr *)
) {
    int status;
    int ret = 0;
    char buf[4096];
    struct iovec iov = { buf, sizeof buf };
    struct sockaddr_nl snl;
    struct msghdr msg = {
        (void*)&snl,
        sizeof snl,
        &iov, 1, NULL, 0, 0
    };
    struct nlmsghdr *hdr;

    status = recvmsg(sockint, &msg, 0);

    if (status < 0) {
        /* Socket non-blocking so bail out once we have read everything */
        if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno == EAGAIN)
            return ret;
        /* Anything else is an error */
        E_PRINT("recvmsg: %d", "EVT_READ", status);
        perror("ERROR read_netlink: ");
        return status;
    } else if (status == 0) {
        E_PRINT("recvmsg: EOF", "EVT_READ");
    }

    /* We need to handle more than one message per 'recvmsg' */
    for (
        hdr = (struct nlmsghdr *) buf;
        NLMSG_OK (hdr, (unsigned int)status);
        hdr = NLMSG_NEXT (hdr, status)
    ) {
        /* Finish reading */
        if (hdr->nlmsg_type == NLMSG_DONE)
            return ret;

        /* Message is some kind of error */
        if (hdr->nlmsg_type == NLMSG_ERROR) {
            E_PRINT("Decode to be done", "EVT_READ");
            return -1;
        }
        /* Call message handler */
        if (msg_handler) {
            ret = (*msg_handler)(hdr);
            if (ret < 0) {
                E_PRINT("msg_handler: %d", "EVT_READ", ret);
                return ret;
            }
        } else {
            E_PRINT("NULL message handler", "EVT_READ");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
static int msg_handler(struct nlmsghdr *msg)
{
    struct ifinfomsg *ifi = NLMSG_DATA(msg);
    struct ifaddrmsg *ifa = NLMSG_DATA(msg);
    char ifname[1024];

    switch (msg->nlmsg_type) {
    case RTM_NEWADDR:
        if_indextoname(ifa->ifa_index, ifname);
        printf("RTM NEWADDR %s\n", ifname);
        break;
    case RTM_DELADDR:
        if_indextoname(ifa->ifa_index, ifname);
        printf("RTM DELADDR %s\n", ifname);
        break;
    case RTM_NEWLINK:
        if_indextoname(ifi->ifi_index, ifname);
        printf("RTM NEWLINK %s %s\n",
            ifname,
            (ifi->ifi_flags & IFF_UP) ? "UP" : "DOWN"
        );
        break;
    case RTM_DELLINK:
        if_indextoname(ifi->ifi_index, ifname);
        printf("RTM DELLINK %s\n", ifname);
        break;
    default:
        fprintf(stderr,
            "RTM UNKNOWN nlmsg_type %d\n",
            msg->nlmsg_type
        );
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int nls = open_netlink();
    if (nls < 0) {
        E_PRINT("Open Error!", "INIT");
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "Monitoring\n");
    while (1)
        event_read(nls, msg_handler);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ip monitor link` will do just that, no need to rewrite the `iproute2` tools. Unless you really have to. And then, their source code offers a better, more complete example of netlink programming.

Comment: It is not supposed to be complete, rather minimal. It is not meant to be a replacement but an example. It is not a rewrite of iproute. It is merely a short minimalistic example. What people use or do is not my business, -

Comment: and just typing `ip monitor link` is even more minimal.